# Populating select dropdown using nested objects of Model [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a select dropdown which needs to be prepopulated with the array of objects. However, the ngModel doesn't bind with the data. I've tried to demonstrate it in simpler way, but in reality, I have a home page, when I navigate from home page to contact Page, I need to populate the form data. If I directly enter the contact page, the form must be empty.

In the below example, to make it simpler, I am populating the data on page load, but issue I am facing is similar to my former example, ngModel of select doesn't get updated with data from JSON.

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular';
adViewList: AdViewModel = new AdViewModel();
callListType = [
   {
  callType: {
    'id': 1,
    'description': 'description1',
   }
},
{
  callType: {
    'id': 2,
    'description': 'description2',
  },
}

]
compareByOptionId(idFist, idSecond) {
return idFist && idSecond && idFist.callType.description ===    idSecond;
}
prepopulateData = {
inciNum: "12365",
callType: {
    'id': 2,
  'description': 'description2',      
  }
}

ngOnInit() { // on page load
const someDate:any = this.prepopulateData;
this.adViewList = someDate
}
}
export class AdViewModel {
inciNum: string;
callType = Availability;
}

export class Availability {
id: string;
description: string;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputcomplaint" aria-describedby="complaintHelp" 
autocomplete="new-password" name="complaint" 
[(ngModel)]="adViewList.inciNum" #complaint="ngModel">

<select [(ngModel)]="adViewList.callType.description"
              [compareWith]="compareByOptionId">
              <option style="display:none"></option>
              <option *ngFor="let data of callListType" [ngValue]="data">
                {{data.callType.description}} </option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rxrxv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: As @Arragon say, the problem is that your select asign to the model an object of type CallListType, when use [ngValue] in the options, you asign the value of all the object. So you must make that the model was **adViewList.callType** -and change the compare function too-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following and it seems to work. Notice the change. I'm mapping `[(ngModel)]="adViewList.callType"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="adViewList"` because, `callListType` is a list of `callType` not `AdViewModel`

Also note, I'm printing the `<p> List: {{adViewList | json}} </p>` to check if the model is getting updated and it seems to be getting the values from what is selected.

Update: To have the default value appear as per the onNgInit() you have, you need to change `ngValue` to `[ngValue]="data.callType"` and the compare function needs to check ids, not objects. See code below.

Try this:
In your template:

```
<select name="select" [(ngModel)]="adViewList.callType"
                  [compareWith]="compareByOptionId">
                  <option style="display:none"></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let data of callListType" [ngValue]="data.callType">
                    {{data.callType.description}} </option>
</select>
```

In the component:

```
  compareByOptionId(idFist, idSecond) {
    return idFist.id === idSecond.id
  }
```

PS: Sorry, I do not have a stackblitz id to share what I tested, I just edited your files to test.

Comment: I changed ngModel value to adViewList.callType, now it populates the first item in the callListType, irrespective of the property present in prepopulateData array.

Comment: Are you sure? I just re-tested this code again, it seem to get the call type object based on selection. Obviously, the iciNum will remain same because that is not part of CallType.

Comment: can you please post the working stackblitz link with your changes? I've tested it, it doesn't return expected data. In ngOnInit, we are assigning the value of dropdown to  'description2', however, I don't see that result.

Comment: adViewList  data is printed correctly as you mentioned, however dropdown is not populated with that value.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1. `ngValue` is invalid, change it to `[value]`
2. your binding is wrong, you need to match the `[(ngModel)]="someValue"` to the `[value]="someValue"` as it is your model id.

**SOLUTION**: Change `[ngValue]="data"` to `[value]="data.callType.description"` like this:

```
<select name="select" [(ngModel)]="adViewList.callType.description" [compareWith]="compareByOptionId">
  <option style="display:none"></option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of callListType" [value]="data.callType.description">
    {{data.callType.description}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**NOTE:** I suggest you to work with the `id` property instead of the `description` property as value like this:

`[(ngModel)]="adViewList.callType.id"`

`[value]="data.callType.id"`

Comment: I made the above changes, it is defaulted to first item in array instead of the value present in prepopulated data. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hog93k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
 I wonder if there are any changes I need to make to AdminViewModel for its nested objects.